# ASP.Net, MS-Access Date/Time Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I get the time but problem in time format. I useing the Repeater.

> > My Database:MS-Access 
> >  
> > My Database Column: gun(Date/Time-Short Date)
> >  basSaat(Date/Time-Medium Time)
> >  
> >     bitisSaat(Date/Time-Medium Time) 
> > proje(Long Text)
> >     kulID(Integer-Auto Increment)

My Repeater code giris.aspx:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <table align="center" class="table table-bordered table-striped datatable dataTable" >
                <tr>
                   <thead>
                         <th class="sorting_asc">Saat Aralığı</th>
                         <th class="sorting_asc">Proje Adi</th>
                         <th class="sorting_asc">İşlem</th>
                    </thead>
               </tr>      

        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
         <thbody>
             <tr class="odd">
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"basSaat") %>-<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"bitisSaat") %></td>
            <td><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"proje") %></td>
            <td><a href="duzenle.aspx?id=<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"id") %>">Düzenle</a></td>
             </tr>
        </thbody>
        </ItemTemplate>
        <FooterTemplate></table></FooterTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

---

Saat Aralığı| Proje Adı    | İşlem

> 30.12.1899 14:10:00-30.12.1899 15:20:00 | Roxa Digital | Düzenle(Edit)

---

I want This
Saat Aralığı| Proje Adı    | İşlem
14:10-15:20|Roxa Digital   |Düzenle(Edit)

giris.aspx.cs file

```
    sorgu.CommandText = "select * from calisan where kulID=@ID AND gun=@date";
    sorgu.Parameters.Add("@ID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = sesionKulId;
    sorgu.Parameters.Add("@date", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = bugun;
    sorgu.Connection = baglanti;
    baglanti.Open();
    oku = sorgu.ExecuteReader();
    if (oku.HasRows) { 
    Repeater1.DataSource = oku;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
    oku.Dispose();}
    else{
        Repeater1.Visible = false;
        repeaterBos.Text = "Bugün Hiç Çalışma Yapmamışsınız...";
        oku.Dispose();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which field is your date in the repeater as it is in Turkish (?) but you can add a third parameter into the DataBinder.Eval() function that piggybacks the String.Format() function to format the date (if the data type is a date from the database) according to any given format like so:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"bitisSaat", "{0:d.M.yyyy hh:mm:ss}") %>
```

Comment: `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"bitisSaat", "{0:HH:mm}") %>` Thank you :)